# Unable to connect remote host through net/ssh

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

This is pretty weird. I have my public key added at host machine. I can simply run

```
ssh -p <port> -l <username> hostt.com
```

which simply opens the remote shell. I can even run my capistrano scripts for the deployments on the same machine. But when i was trying connect with this following simple ruby script

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'

Net::SSH.start("hostt.com", 
               :port => <port>, 
               :username => <username>
              ) do |session|
  puts session.pwd
end
```

it refuses immediately with the following exception:

```
`initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Click the "tick" on the answers to your question that you accept. It adds to the reputation of those who bothered to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, now after a few days when I look back to the problem, I got a quick success with the following tweak:

```
Net::SSH.start("<host>", "<user>", :port => "<port>") { |ssh|
  puts "logged in"
  puts ssh.exec!("ls -l")  
} rescue puts "failed to connect."
```

So the difference with the previous one is the username, which in this case is passed as the second argument rather than like an option key.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to provide the location of your SSH key, or a password to use with the username you provide in the SSH.start parameters. for the keys, you need to pass the map value as an array `:keys => ["path_to_key"]`. I'm not sure why the api is set up that way, but it is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jed, but this is not fixing the issue :(